# Trouble calling Lambda function (from Lex)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I initialize my Lambda function in Python from Lex, however, whenever my chatbot gets to the specific intent to call it, I get this error message:

> An error has occurred: The server encountered an error processing the
> Lambda response

When I open Monitor tab in my Lambda /Logs, I can see nothing in there.

The beginning of my code in Python is as follows:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    logger.debug('event.bot.name=%s', event['bot']['name'])
    logger.debug('userId=%s, intentName=%s', event['userId'], event['currentIntent']['name'])

    ...then some code

    return close(
        session_attributes,
        'OK. See you then!',
    )
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is `close()`?

Comment: @GSSwain That should be called to end an intent. But I tried very basic vanilla code as described in the documentation and it doesn't work either. It just seems the function doesn't get to called.

Comment: Is this something you wrote, I don't see the import for close in the code.

Comment: @GSSwain My bad... It's in a separate class I import into the code but didn't included in here. Anyway, I tried a very basic code as per doumentation an it doesn't seem working either.